# how to hide Gridview row values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have Gridview control with 21 rows.Some of the rows have 0 values.My requirement is to set background color(consist 0 values Rows) as well as hide the values(means 0's).I can able to set background color.But the thing is,I am not able to hide row values.I have written this line of code, gridSellIn.Rows[0].Visible = false; .Total row is hiding.Make sure i have to show rows back ground color without values.Is this possible in asp.net.[image]

Comment: You want to show the row, but hide the values?

Comment: Absalutely.Because that row has back ground color.I have not mentioned  color in image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the grid RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (...){
            //hide controls
            foreach (Control c in e.Row.Controls)
            {
                 c.Visible=false;
            }
            //change color
            e.Row.Style.Add("background-color","red");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In GridView1_RowDataBound event do the following with rows in which you want no values.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
             e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.but this code is not fulfill my requirement.please read again and see image.please help

Answer (score 0):

You could do this is the DataBinding Event.

```
protected void GRIDVIEW_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(GridViewRow grv in GRIDVIEW.Rows)
   {
     grv.Visible = (Condition_to_check_if_value_loaded_is_zero);
   }
}
```